# MVC4: Child Model in partial View has same ID ( creating a comment for an article)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an Article Model and a Comment Model. 
The ArticleDetail View shows the Article, the Comments to the article and a formular to create a new comment.

When creating a new comment for an article, it has the same id like the article.
In public ActionResult DisplayCreateComment(CommentModel comment, int articleID)
the CommentModel has the same ID as the article.

So every posted comment will have the same ID, and this isn't working. Why has the comment the same id like the article, and how can i solve this?

CommentModel:

```
    public class CommentModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public Article Art { get; set; }
     }
```

ArticleModel:

```
public class ArticleModel
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
...
}
```

ArticleDetail View:

```
...
@Html.Partial("DisplayComments", Model.Comments)
@Html.Action("DisplayCreateComment", "Home", new { articleID = Model.ID })
...
```

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCreateComment(int articleID)
    {            
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayCreateComment(CommentModel comment, int articleID)
    {
        ... 
     //There the CommentModel has the same ID as the Article Model ...


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `ArticleId` in your `CommentModel`. Add the following to your `CommentModel` in addition to what you already have.

```
[ForeignKey("ArticleModel"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ArticleId { get; set; }

public virtual ArticleModel ArticleModel { get; set; }
```

More help on your problem here:

[Matt Blagden From Zero to Blog in 100 Minutes](http://www.mattblagden.com/Blog/Post/From_Zero_to_Blog_in_100_Minutes). 
This can help you create an entire blog, but it does not use `Entity Framework Code First`.

[Scott Allen's Plural Sight Video](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4). 
There is a trial version you can use. This will show you how to implement `one-to-many` objects. There is `Department` and `Employee` You can create your Department (Article) then be able to add Employees (Comments) in the same way.

Basically, you would have to create your Article first, then add comments to it while inside Article's detail. All you have to do is have a `Create link` inside Article Detail.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create an comment", "Create", "Comment", 
                 new {ArticleId = @Model.ArticleId}, null)
```

Create a CommentViewModel class in Models folder/ViewModels folder

```
public class CreateCommentViewModel 
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }        
}
```

Then, have your Create Actions in Comment Controller look like this;

```
    [HttpGet]        
    public ActionResult Create(int articleId)
    {
        var model = new CreateCommentViewModel();
        model.ArticleId= articleId;
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateCommentViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new EfDb();

            var article= _db.Articles.Single(d => d.Id == viewModel.ArticleId);
            var comment= new Comment();
            comment.Text = viewModel.Text;
            comment.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            article.Comments.Add(comment);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("detail", "article", new {id = viewModel.ArticleId});
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: nothing has changed. the Comment has always the same ID as the Article

Comment: @Rubasinum Is `DisplayCreateComment(CommentModel comment, int articleID)` for creating or for displaying the comment? you have provided empty `Actions`, without assessing the logic you have tried, its hard to help. The answer here only creates the relationship between `Article and Comment`

Comment: @Rubasinum i have added more to the answer, i hope that good enough to help you move along.

Comment: mh, this is not working for me. May I have to explain it in a better way. DisplayCreateComment, is for Creating a new Comment.

Comment: in the `[HttpPost] public ActionResult DisplayCreateComment(CommentModel comment, int articleID)` the CommentModel has the same ID, like the Article. I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: so the problem is not the article, it is the comment. Because it has always the same ID like the article

Comment: thanks for your edits, but i dont want to create a link in the article detail. like you described I use `@Html.Action` because I want to Display the Create Comment View directly under the Article Detail. And only then it is the problem that the Comment has the same ID like the Article. That is the reason why i return partial Views in the controller

Comment: RedirectToAction is not working for @HTML.Action:
Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.